# How i join two mysql table using php?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two table in mysql database. Database name frschool. First table name 'profile' fields id, invoice,name and second table name is 'exam' fields id, invoice, obt.mark.
Now how i join the tables for showing data in a one page .

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to join 'profile' table with 'exam' table you need to have in 'exam' table also the field idProfile or some field to make a connection between the 2 tables